# Why is logcat through ADB different from the system logcat?

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I've an app that generates logcat with the following command:

```
logcat -d -v time -t 1620059528.0 *:W
```

However, its output is different from the output I get if I run the exact same command from the console via

```
adb logcat -d -v time -t 1620059528.0 *:W
```

The logs begin at different times, one is much bigger than the other, the output is different.

Why is this? Running Android 11 here.

**EDIT:** I am calling logcat through

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d -v time -t 1620059528.0 *:W");
```

Does this prints ONLY the logcat from the running package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, apps can only access their own logs since Android 4.1 for security reasons.

This is expanded on in [this Android StackExchange answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/7260/163884), which also mentions you can (allegedly, and in 2013) gain full device log access if you own the device with:

```
adb shell pm grant <pkg> android.permission.READ_LOGS
```